# How to uncheck the checkbox of a jquery table when changing a combobox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, razor

I have the following question, when I change the value of the combobox, the checkboxes are still marked, with prop the values are unmarked, but this time it does not work, the idea is to reset the marked checkboxes when the value of the checkbox is changed.
Regards.

```
                var cambio = $("#cmbKit").on('change', function () {
                    var checkPoint = !$(this).data('checked');
                    $('#tblCajas input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
                        if (checkPoint == true) {
                            $(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
                            $("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', false);
                        } 
                    });
                });

                if (cambio) {
                    selectedBox = 0;

                    $('#divCalculos').hide();
                    $('#btnPlanificar').hide();
                }
```

Comment: Can you please add your code / what you tried to the question.  That way you will be able to get help quickly.

Comment: please also give some part of the html rendered page, and what you expect to get, and what you get as result - for sure you have a bug because this is work fine

Comment: instead of setting it to false, do this. `$("input[type='checkbox']").removeAttr('checked')` to remove checked

Comment: I can't upload images, I'm new to stackoverflow, but the idea is that I have a combobox that changes the result of a table according to the value of the combobox, what you should do is when you change the combobox again you must uncheck all the checkboxes of the table to be able to select others, but they are still marked.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to reset every checkbox on change event of combobox, you can use below code -

```
$("#cmbKit").change(function() {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', false);
});
```

You shouldn't use any if condition as you are going to reset it after every change event.
Please note that given code will reset all checkboxes on page, add table selector as well in case you have multiple table with different content.
Hope this helps.